# Webpack not re-compiling CSS changes (webpack-dev-server)

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, postcss

I have a project setup like this:

```
/src
  /stylesheets
    main.css
    /ui
      _layouts.css
      _media.css
```

With the `main.css` setup like this:

```
@import 'ui/layouts';
@import 'ui/media';
```

My webpack is setup like this:

```
{ test: /\.css$/i, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'] }
```

The css compiles beautifully, and if I make a change to main.css, it will trigger a recompile, and it'll work fine. But if I make a change to _layouts.css or _media.css, it won't detect the change and I have to restart webpack-dev-server for it to pickup the changes.

Is there something I can change to make this work?

Comment: Hi, Did you check the number of watcher : https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#not-enough-watchers.
it's the old webpack documentation, but it may be the problem